# Binary $[31,22,5]$ code does not exist

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

Consider a binary $[31,22,5]$ linear code. There are $2^{31-22}=2^9$ cosets and we have $t=\frac{5-1}{2}=2$.

I am looking to find a **contradiction**, by considering the number of coset leaders with weights $0,1$ and $2$, and considering, for each coset, an upper bound for the number of words of weight $3$ contained in it.

Any help on finding this two values? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't strings with weight 2 just 4 apart? How many coset leaders can you expect to have that have weights 0,1, and 2?

Comment: @E-A Sorry, I am not following. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: I am confused myself as well, so let me clarify my confusion: it sounds like you want a codeword from each coset of weight 0,1 or 2. However, if you have two codewords that have both weight 2, aren't they already only 4 apart, and not 5?

Comment: I want to know the number of coset leaders with weights 0,1
and 2.  (all together)

Comment: @XuguiManuel What have you tried?  Do you know how many words there are of a given weight?

Comment: @RaviFernando This is all I know, and I don't know where to start.

Comment: @MorganRodgers What is tripping me up is, if 00000...0000 is a codeword, then, how would this question work? Does it not depend on the structure of the code? Does the question also expect to construct a particular codebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{31}{0}+\binom{31}{1}+\binom{31}{2}=497$ of weight equal to or less than $2$. So, we have $2^9-497=15$ cosets of weight greater than $2$. In cosets of weight $2$ there are, at most, $\lfloor{\frac{29}{3}}\rfloor\times\binom{31}{2}=4185$ vectors with weight $3$.

This way, there are $\binom{31}{3}-4185=310$ vectors of weight $3$ that are not in cosets of weight $2$.

Suppose there is a coset of weight $3$, then it has, at most, $\lfloor{\frac{31}{3}}\rfloor=10$ vectors of weight $3$. But it is not possible to distribute $310$ vectors of weight $3$ over $15$ cosets, kowing that each coset has, at most, $10$ vectors of weight $3$. The cases where a coset with weight greater than $4$ would be even worse.

There is no binary [31,22,5] linear code.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to count the weight 3 codewords in each coset; $\mathcal{C}$ contains no weight 3 codeword, and also no weight 1 coset can contain a weight 3 word (I leave it to you to show this).

For a weight 2 coset of the form $u + \mathcal{C}$ with $\mathrm{wt}(u) = 2$, the only way to get a weight 3 word is from a $c \in \mathcal{C}$ with $\mathrm{wt}(c) =5$ and $\mathrm{wt}(u \cap c) = 2$. So if $\{i,j\}$ are the coordinates where $u_{i}=u_{j}=1$, you want to consider how many weight 5 codewords $c$ there can possibly be with $c_{i}=c_{j}=1$, all at distance at least 5 apart. To count these, notice that these codewords cannot be at distance exactly 5, the distance between them must be even since they have the same weight.

Comment: But how do I come up with the number of coset leaders of weights $0,1$ and $2$, all together?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I wasn't really paying attention. Of course, the number of vectors with weight $0,1$ and $2$ is $\binom{31}{0}+\binom{31}{1}+\binom{31}{2}$. Since $d=5$, there are exactly $\binom{31}{0},\binom{31}{1},\binom{31}{2}$ coset leaders with weights $0,1$ and $2$, respectively.

Comment: I understand that cosets of weights $1$ and $2$ don't have weight $3$ codewords in them. The only option is to have weight $3$ codewords in weight $2$ cosets, and that $u_i=u_j=c_i=c_j=1$. I would say an upper bound for this number is $\binom{31}{2}\times\binom{29}{3}$. Is this helpful? How do these computations lead to a contradiction?

Comment: Eventually I had already figured it out, but thanks for the answer!